# RPM is skipping packages. Need to install 2 architecture versions

Tags: rpm

I want to install a bunch of packages, both 32bit and 64bit.
When I'm executing

I'm getting something like

```
$ rpm -ihv pkg.i386 pkg.x86_64
warning: package pkg.i386 was already added, skipping pkg.x86_64
```

The problem is, that there are not just 2 packages, rather a few hundred (kind of an OS upgrade) including glibc for example. Also, some packages depend on both architecture versions. In the end, it fails because of unmet dependencies (because of its skipping packages)

How does rpm decide whether or not to install both versions?

Can I tell or force rpm to install both?

Note: This is a minimal System with no yum on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy workaround for this. Neither via rpm nor via yum. 
I had to specifically change the spec files of the rpm's to fulfill the requirements (depend on certain libs)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following entry in  `/etc/yum.conf` file

```
multilib_policy=all
```

Comment: Unfortunately, This is a minimal System with no yum on it. (I will edit the question to clarify that)